# JSON Object returned from PHP is NULL

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, google-api

I am trying to send a javascript variable (placeid) to PHP using AJAX. I use this variable to retrieve a JSON Object. The JSON returned to Javascript is NULL. How do I fix this?

```
function sendToPhp(placeid){
var url = "finals.php?placeid="+placeid;
var getJSONObj=function(url,callback){
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
httpc.open("GET", url, true);
httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpc.responseType='json';
httpc.onload= function(){
    var status=httpc.status;
    if(status==200){
        //alert(httpc.response);
        callback(null,httpc.response);
    }
    else{
        callback(status,httpc.response);
         }
   };
httpc.send();
 };

  getJSONObj(url,function(err,jsonObjectReturned){

    if(err!==null){
        alert("something went wrong"+ err);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("success");
        alert(jsonObjectReturned);   // **returns NULL**
    }
});
}  // end of function
```

The PHP script uses the placeid to return a JSON file as shown:

```
    if(isset($_GET['placeid']))
    {
        $placeid= $_GET['placeid'];
        $apikey="someKeyValue";
        $url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=".$placeid."&key=".$apikey;
        $jsonPlacesObject=json_decode(htmlspecialchars(@file_get_contents($url),true),true);
        echo json_encode($jsonPlacesObject);  //sending json to javascript**
        die();
    }
```

Comment: if `**//sending json to javascript**` is in your document, your script isn't valid. Also why do you decode json then re-encode it? Infact, why arn't you going direct to the google map API?

Comment: @Scuzzy To convert it into a string

Comment: Thak makes little sense to me.

Comment: Don't try to debug several things at once.  Is `placeid` being received by the script?  What is the content of `$jsonPlacesobject`?  If these are all what you expect, then diagnose the AJAX.  But I would bet that you aren't getting valid JSON data to work with.

Comment: @TimMorton The JSON is valid and isn't empty.

Comment: Are you referring to `echo json_encode($jsonPlacesObject);` when you say the JSON is valid?  If that's the case (BTW, I would just use the JSON from google without munging it up), then you need to make sure that's all you're sending back via AJAX.  Any content other than that will mess things up.  Use your browser console to see what is being sent back.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX form looks wrong. Try reading https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp .

Original.

Comment: I am using a callback. Can you point out why the JSON returned is NULL?

Comment: I got this error: InvalidStateError: responseText is only available if responseType is '' or 'document'.

Comment: in your php code, $jsonPlacesObject=json_decode(htmlspecialchars(@file_get_contents($url),true),true);    I don't think file_get_contents is right for that job, try curl. Its built for this reason. You might not be getting back the right response you were expecting.

Comment: Nope, still getting NULL as result.

Comment: is curl turned on?